# Distribute Labels evenly in certain space

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to fill a given space with an unknown width with an unknown number of labels. So, if the hosting Gridcolumn resizes, all the labels change there width to fill the space **evenly**, i.e. each label has the same width.
So I used an `ItemsControl` in combination with a `Stackpanel`. However, the `Stackpanel` does, what it is supposed to do... stacking the items. A `Dockpanel` offers only the fill the space for the LastChild.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Months" Grid.Column="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Month, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DockPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>   
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0: MM-yy}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Use a UniformGrid with a single Row.

Comment: Wouldn't i have to set Grid.Column for every Label?

Comment: Of course not, a UniformGrid is not a Grid.

Comment: You are right. Thank you!